# Changing the name of a dataframe inside of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I am working with a folder of csv files. These files were imported using the following code:

```r
data_frame <- list.files("path", pattern = ".csv", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

csv_data <- lapply(data_frame, read.csv)

names(csv_data) <- gsub(".csv","", 
                        list.files("path", pattern = ".csv", all.files = TRUE, full.names = FALSE),
                        fixed = TRUE)
```

After this has been generated the dataframes hold the name of the csv. Since I have over 3000 csv files, I was wondering how to change the name of them to keep track of them better.

For example, instead of 'City, State, US', it will generate 'City-State-US'.

I apologize if this has already been asked, but I cannot find anything that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand your question correctly, you have CSV files names "City, State, US.csv" (so "Chicago, IL, USA.csv", etc.), you are reading them in to R and storing them in a list where the list element name is the CSV name, and you want to make some changes to that element name?

You can access the names of the list item using `names(csv_data)`, as you did above, and then treat it however you like and write it back to the same.

For instance, the example you gave:

```
names(csv_data) <- gsub(", ", "-", names(csv_data), fixed = TRUE)
```

This should do what you need. If you need to do something else, just change the gsub parameters or function to something else - the key is that you can extract and write back the list item names in one shot.

You are already sort of doing this with the third line, where you name the items - you could even make the treatment before you assign the names.

Edit: Also, a quick note: You are already storing the output of list.files in the data_frame variable - you could just reuse that variable in the third line instead of calling list.files again.